# Django: Execute function and print result in template without refresh

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using django to develop my website. In this page I have x as input, when i press enter a function will be executed and then the page will refresh and the result will be displayed.
I would like to make it dynamic: capture input,  execute function and show the result then another tag appears etc..
I will be very thankful.

This is my python code:

```
def console (request):
    import paramiko
    import time
    import getpass
    import re

    ip = '192.168.43.10'

    username = 'osboxes'
    password = 'osboxes.org'

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=username, password=password,
                look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    print('Successfully connected to %s' % ip)
    remote_conn = ssh.invoke_shell()

    time.sleep(.005)
    output = remote_conn.recv(65535)
    print (output)
    def escape_ansi(line):
        ansi_escape = re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
        return ansi_escape.sub('', str(line))
    x=request.GET['x']
    time.sleep(1)
    remote_conn.send(x+'\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if remote_conn.recv_ready():
        output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
        op=output.decode()
        oo=escape_ansi(op)

    return render(request,'shell.html', {'oo' : oo})
```

This is my html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="mb-3 card text-white card-body" style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
        <h5 class="text-white card-title">Console log to the gateway</h5>
            <form action="console">  
                <div class="position-relative form-group" >
                        <input rows="15" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51)" name="x" id="x" class="form-control"> 
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <h3>result : {{oo}}</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to add ajax functionality to your code. Better start with jquery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You can't update the page without a refresh unless you use some form of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand the concept "Rendering", when server finish something and then it will return result to render HTML. At this time, server have not any connection with the page.
This process is one-way.

I think that you are searching something like [jsf_ajax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_ajax.htm). but Django have no anything like it.